# One JS function to handle output from 3 sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am unsuccessfully trying to squeze the first three functions into one, so that one function can handle different outputs from three different sliders instead of creating the same functions 3 times for different elements. Is there a good way to do it?

```js
  var x = document.getElementById("fader1");
    x.addEventListener("mousemove", function(input){
         document.getElementById("protein").value = x.value;
    });

    var y = document.getElementById("fader2");
    y.addEventListener("mousemove", function(input){
        document.getElementById("carbs").value = y.value;
    });

    var z = document.getElementById("fader3");
    z.addEventListener("mousemove", function(input){
        document.getElementById("fat").value = z.value;
    });


    $(function(){
        $(".bar").on("input", function () {
            var val1 = $("#fader1").val();
            var val2 = $("#fader2").val();
            var val3 = $("#fader3").val();

            var sum = (val1*4) + (val2*4) + (val3*9);
            $("#sum").text(sum);

        switch (true) {
            case (sum <= 600):
                $("#sum").css("color", "red");
                break;
            case (sum > 601 && sum <= 1200):
                $("#sum").css("color", "yellow");
                break;
            case (sum > 1200):
                $("#sum").css("color", "orange");
                break;
            default:
                $("#sum").css("color", "red");
        };
        });
    });
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="protein">
            <p>Protein</p>
            <output id="protein"></output>
            <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="" id="fader1" class="bar">
        </div>
        <div class="carbs">
            <p>Carbohydrates</p>
            <output id="carbs"></output>
            <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="" id="fader2" class="bar">
        </div>
        <div class="fat">
            <p>Fat</p>
            <output id="fat"></output>
            <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="" id="fader3" class="bar">
        </div>
        <div class="total">
            <p>Calories: </p>
            <div id="sum">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `input` event and traverse to the current `<output>` using [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/). This also allows you to trigger the input event on page load to fill in the text values.

Using another event on top of the input event doesn't make sense

```js
$(".bar").on("input", function() {
  // "this" is current input event occurs on - set output value accordingly
  $(this).prev().val($(this).val());

  var val1 = $("#fader1").val();
  var val2 = $("#fader2").val();
  var val3 = $("#fader3").val();

  var sum = (val1 * 4) + (val2 * 4) + (val3 * 9);
  $("#sum").text(sum);
  // css switch removed for clarity   

  // now trigger the event on page load
}).trigger('input');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="protein">
    <p>Protein</p>
    <output id="protein"></output>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="" id="fader1" class="bar">
  </div>
  <div class="carbs">
    <p>Carbohydrates</p>
    <output id="carbs"></output>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="" id="fader2" class="bar">
  </div>
  <div class="fat">
    <p>Fat</p>
    <output id="fat"></output>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="" id="fader3" class="bar">
  </div>
  <div class="total">
    <p>Calories: </p>
    <div id="sum">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Seems like I have some reviewing to do.

Comment: All part of the learning curve. To be honest I didn't even know there was such an `<output>` element. Do note however it isn't supported in IE. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, create a function and call it with different `ids`, like below using [previousSibling](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_previoussibling.asp)

```
setValues('fader1');
setValues('fader2');
setValues('fader3');
```

```js
// our function for setting values
function setValues(id) {
    var x = document.getElementById(id);
    x.addEventListener("mousemove", function(){
       x.previousElementSibling.innerHTML = x.value;
    });
}

setValues('fader1');
setValues('fader2');
setValues('fader3');


$(function(){
    $(".bar").on("input", function () {
        var val1 = $("#fader1").val();
        var val2 = $("#fader2").val();
        var val3 = $("#fader3").val();

        var sum = (val1*4) + (val2*4) + (val3*9);
        $("#sum").text(sum);

        switch (true) {
            case (sum <= 600):
                $("#sum").css("color", "red");
                break;
            case (sum > 601 && sum <= 1200):
                $("#sum").css("color", "yellow");
                break;
            case (sum > 1200):
                $("#sum").css("color", "orange");
                break;
            default:
                $("#sum").css("color", "red");
        };
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="protein">
        <p>Protein</p>
        <output id="protein"></output>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="" id="fader1" class="bar">
    </div>
    <div class="carbs">
        <p>Carbohydrates</p>
        <output id="carbs"></output>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="" id="fader2" class="bar">
    </div>
    <div class="fat">
        <p>Fat</p>
        <output id="fat"></output>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="" id="fader3" class="bar">
    </div>
    <div class="total">
        <p>Calories: </p>
        <div id="sum">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="protein">
            <p>Protein</p>
            <output id="protein"></output>
            <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="" id="fader1" class="bar">
        </div>
        <div class="carbs">
            <p>Carbohydrates</p>
            <output id="carbs"></output>
            <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="" id="fader2" class="bar">
        </div>
        <div class="fat">
            <p>Fat</p>
            <output id="fat"></output>
            <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="" id="fader3" class="bar">
        </div>
        <div class="total">
            <p>Calories: </p>
            <div id="sum">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

     $('input').mousemove(function(){
        $(this).siblings('output').val($(this).val());
     })


    $(function(){
        $(".bar").on("input", function () {
            var valueElements = $('input');
            var sum = (valueElements[0].value *4) + (valueElements[1].value*4) + (valueElements[2].value*9);
            $("#sum").text(sum);

        switch (true) {
            case (sum <= 600):
                $("#sum").css("color", "red");
                break;
            case (sum > 601 && sum <= 1200):
                $("#sum").css("color", "yellow");
                break;
            case (sum > 1200):
                $("#sum").css("color", "orange");
                break;
            default:
                $("#sum").css("color", "red");
        };
        });
    }); 

    </script>
</body>
```